# 'Unhandled Rejection" in feathers.js

Tags: javascript, rest, feathersjs

I've written this piece of code:

```
const reports = this.app.service('generate-reports');

var job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '* * * * * *',
  onTick: await reports => {

    var current_date = moment().hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0).toISOString();
    var data = {
      date: current_date,
    };
    await reports.patch(null, data);
  },
  start: false,
  timeZone: 'Europe/Warsaw'
});
job.start();
```

But when I try tu run it, i get this error:

```
info: Feathers application started on http://localhost:3030
error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  Promise {
<rejected> TypeError: Cannot read property 'patch' of undefined
```

What's the issue? Thanks in advance for any help ;)

Comment: `Unhandled Rejection` is thrown when you fail to provide a `reject` callback to a `Promise`, either via `catch` or the constructor. It looks like you're trying to access `reports` before it's defined

Comment: This usually means that the `'generate-reports'` service does not exist (yet?). You might have more luck putting `const reports = this.app.service('generate-reports');` into the `onTick: await reports => {` function (lookups are pretty quick so you won't have any performance hits).